# Prettyphoto gallery in jquery-mobile.1.1.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, image-gallery, prettyphoto

PrettyPhoto is showing individual images, but the gallery isn't working. This is how the image is being rendered on the browser:

```
<a href="/images/reviews/full/2/ii_15986_1429535345455.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[reviewsgallery]" class="ui-link" sl-processed="1">
    <img itemprop="photo" src="/images/reviews/full/2/ii_15986_1429535345455.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
</a>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    });
});
```

I had to use "data-rel" as "rel" refreshes the page in jQuery-mobile.1.1.1.

Comment: I think that prettyPhoto requires rel attribute for building a gallery-set of images. If you are forced to use data-rel attribute for inicialization instead of rel, it will work fine if you want to initialize standalone image lightbox, but prettyPhoto will probably still look for rel attribute to build the gallery.

Comment: @Vladiks In the jQuery, it says "hook: 'rel;", do you reckon I could change that and any other references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, just use:

```
<a href="/images/reviews/full/2/ii_15986_1429535345455.jpg" data-pretty-photo="prettyPhoto[reviewsgallery]" class="ui-link" sl-processed="1">
    <img itemprop="photo" src="/images/reviews/full/2/ii_15986_1429535345455.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
</a>
```

and in javascript:

```
jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    hook : 'data-pretty-photo'  
});
```

and it should work fine. I can't find it in the documentation, but it's visible in the source:

```
hook: 'rel', /* the attribute tag to use for prettyPhoto hooks. default: 'rel'. For HTML5, use "data-rel" or similar. */
```

Comment: I tried this already and the page refreshed and replaces the last part of the URL.

Comment: The page refreshed and stayed on the same screen? Strange. It's hard to tell what is happening without live example, I'm sorry.

Comment: So say you have www.test.com/hello/this-page, the page refreshes on click, the gallery appears but the page is www.test.com/hello/prettyPhoto[gallery].